# Ranquear database [#1 de 10]

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, paginação

Preciso ranquear os registros do DB durante a paginação. A principio não pretendo criar um campo para o ranking. Supondo ter 10 registros

<sub>**`1) Ordenando a paginação por AZ, quero listar com o número correspondente ao rank - #N de 10`**</sub>
<sub>**`2) Quando exibir o conteúdo, preciso o número correspondente ao rank - #N de 10`**</sub>

<sub>**• PAGINAÇÃO**</sub>
<sub>#01 de 10, Lorem ipsum</sub>
<sub>#02 de 10, Lorem ipsum</sub>
<sub>...</sub>
<sub>#10 de 10, Lorem ipsum</sub>

```
SELECT *,
FIND_IN_SET( score,
    ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score ORDER BY score DESC ) FROM table )
) AS rank
FROM table limit X,X
```

---

<sub>**• CONTEÚDO**</sub>
<sub>Lorem ipsum, Ranking #03 de 10</sub>

```
SELECT *,
FIND_IN_SET( score,
    ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score ORDER BY score DESC ) FROM table )
) AS rank
FROM table WHERE ...
```

---

Peguei essa SQL de um exemplo e está funcionando, mas eu não domino MYSQL e não tenho conhecimento para este caso...
Gostaria de saber se há outra forma para montar esta QUERY... Aceito sugestões.

Comment: Para facilitar o entendimento seria preciso que você postasse a estrutura da tabela do banco de dados usado!

Comment: @Willams de Jesus, não precisa da estrutura do DB pois pretendo ordenar pela ordem crescente e não há uma chave que valha como pontuação. O exemplo que postei eu encontrei no `stackexchange` - funciona mas é baseado em pontos(`TBL-SCORE`)

Comment: O que você chama de rank? O número da linha no resultado?

Comment: Não estou entendendo bem. Então você não quer um campo como o *score* dos seus exemplos? E a tal numeração seria baseada em que? Na ordem alfabética dos resultados de cada página?

Comment: @bfavaretto sim, supondo que o ID 05 na paginação seja listado como #2 no rank AZ, gostaria também que quando acessar o conteúdo ele também faça o calculo para exibir `Posição 2 de 10`.

Answer (score 5):

Não entendi se é isso que você quer, mas se é apenas a numeração das linhas da saída, pode fazer algo desta forma:

```
SELECT
    @linha := @linha + 1 AS contador,
    tabela_desejada.*
FROM
    (SELECT @linha := 35) AS nada,
    --                 ^ Usar o mesmo valor inicial do limit
    tabela_desejada
LIMIT 35,10;
--     ^ Usar o mesmo valor inicial da subquery
```

> - Notar que a *subquery* com o valor de exemplo 35 tem que usar o mesmo valor inicial do limit. Provavelmente, como a query será gerada dinamicamente, basta usar o mesmo parâmetro nos dois lugares.
> - Lembre-se também de que o `limit` do MySQL se inicia do zero.
>     Para iniciar de 1 na saída, basta fazer `( @linha := @linha + 1 ) + 1 ...`

### Versão com totalizador:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT( "#", @linha := @linha + 1, " de ", total.cnt ) AS ranking,
    tabela_desejada.*
FROM
    (SELECT @linha := 35) AS nada,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tabela_desejada) AS total,
    tabela_desejada
ORDER BY nome
LIMIT 35,10;
```

Neste caso, se você for usar `WHERE`, lembre de replicar a condição na *query* principal **e** na *subquery*:

```
...
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tabela_desejada WHERE id > 100) AS total,
    --                                                     ^ atenção
    tabela_desejada
WHERE id > 100
--       ^ atenção
ORDER BY nome
LIMIT 35,10;
```

Comment: @PapaCharlie caso você queira realmente complicar :), e fazer com que o ranking não se altere com o WHERE, o caminho é passar o contador para dentro da subquery. Assim, a contagem é feita na base toda, antes do resultado ser filtrado (com uma penalização no processamento, obviamente).

Comment: usei como critério a ordem AZ com o intuito de simplificar propositalmente, pois eu preciso compreender como funciona a QUERY, e posteriormente aplicar às necessidades usando algumas médias. Vou botar o seu exemplo em prática e depois dou um feedback. +1 pelas explicações dadas.

Answer (score 1):

Tomando como base o seu exemplo, basta modificar os campos da subselect para ficar de acordo com o seus critérios: (obter o rank ordenado pelo nome de AaZ)

```
SELECT *,
FIND_IN_SET( id,
    ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( id ORDER BY nome ASC ) FROM `table` )
) AS rank
FROM `table` order by nome;
```

E para pegar um registro:

```
SELECT *,
FIND_IN_SET( id,
    ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( id ORDER BY nome ASC ) FROM `table` )
) AS rank,
( SELECT COUNT( id ) FROM `table` ) AS total
FROM `table` where id=5;
```

Ou seja, o FIND_IN_SET procura o id 5 na lista de ids (1,3,5,8,4,10,9,6,7,2) que foi ordenada pelo nome, retornando a posição 3...

Veja o funcionamento no sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a84a9/4