# Sequência numérica

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um  banco de dados (MySQL) com uns 100 clientes cadastrados e estou criando uma tabela (*ranking*) de compras desses clientes, sei que o banco cria um ID *autoincrement*, gostaria de colocar nessa tabela só os primeiros 20 clientes que compram mais produtos e logo teria o numero de colocação no *ranking* e o nome, mas não estou conseguindo.

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente resolver na base de dados é o melhor caminho pro que perguntou.

Na parte que você faz a query:

```
SELECT cliente FROM clientes ORDER BY totalcompras DESC LIMIT 20
```

Se as compras estiverem em outra base (o que provavelmente é o caso), pode usar funções de agrupamento / JOIN ou mesmo subquery.

Para numerar as linhas na saída, pode usar parte desta solução:

> [Ranquear database [#1 de 10]](/questions/29237/70)

Comment: Olá Bacco, valew pela dica. Eu queria colocar a cada cliente selecionado do banco o numero de 1 á 20 na frente. Ex. 1 - Joäo (Sendo que o ID no BD é 33), 2 - Maria (Sendo que ID no BD é 55) e assim por diante até chegar até o 20.

Comment: Como o próprio Bacco já recomendou [em outra resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29237/ranquear-database-1-de-10/29283#29283), você pode incluir um contador na query: `SELECT @linha := @linha + 1 AS contador, cliente FROM clientes ORDER BY totalcompras DESC LIMIT 20`.

Comment: @JorgeToledo chegou a ver a resposta que o bfavaretto indicou? É mais ou menos aquilo que vc precisa?

Comment: E ai galera, Bacco, já consegui fazer e fiz:
$query_clientes = mysql_query ( "select * from clientes " ); while ( $cliente = mysql_fetch_array ( $query_clientes ) ) { $id_cliente = $cliente['id']; $name_cliente = $cliente['name']; if ($query_clientes){ $sequencia++; E deu tudo certo, desde já muito obrigado pela ajuda..