# Numeração sequencial dos resultados de uma query

Tags: sql, query, classificação

Eu não sou lá muito chegado a banco de dados, e na verdade eu nem preciso de tal funcionalidade, mas apenas a título de curiosidade, é possível criar em *runtime*, isto é, durante o SELECT, uma numeração sequencial para ser utilizada em substituição aos valores auto-incrementais de uma chave-primária, sem alterar nenhum valor, apenas facilitando o trabalho da linguagem *server-side*?

Considerem [esse SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e75e7/3/0) de exemplo.

Nele existem três tabelas, sendo que a terceira apenas relaciona as outras duas. Eu sei que esse tipo de tabela intermediária tem um nome próprio, mas eu não lembro >.<

Do jeito que a consulta simples foi montada, ao renderizar um HTML a partir de um recurso dessa consulta, se eu mostrar os valores da coluna **sid** ficaria visualmente estranho, por exemplo, um *rowset* com três registros começar sua listagem pelo número quatro.

Com a linguagem *server-side* bastaria obter o o índice corrente da iteração sobre o recurso e usar esse valor ao invés do presente na coluna. Ou ainda eu poderia montar uma lista não-ordenada e renumerar com CSS(3).

Mas e diretamente pelo *query*? É possível?

Comment: "*Eu sei que esse tipo de tabela intermediária tem um nome próprio, mas eu não lembro*"; chama-se tabela de resolução ou objeto de resolução.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Solução para MySQL:

Considerando que a numeração possa ser volátil, e que o MySQL não tem um contador de linhas por padrão, segue uma query que supre a contagem usando `@variáveis`:

```
SET @contador := 0;
SELECT
   @contador := @contador + 1 AS linha,
   t.campo1,
   t.campo2
FROM
   tabela t
```

Se por alguma razão não puder fazer o `SET` separado:

```
SELECT
   @contador := @contador + 1 AS linha,
   t.campo1,
   t.campo2
FROM
   (SELECT @contador := 0) AS nada,
   tabela t
```

E se quiser numerar o resultado de uma Query complexa

```
SELECT
   @contador := @contador + 1 AS linha,
   t.campo1,
   t.campo2
FROM
   (SELECT @contador := 0) AS nada,
   (SELECT SUM(campo) FROM tabela GROUP BY algumacoisa JOIN outracoisa ... ) AS t
```

Não chega a ser uma reordenação de chave primária, mas se for apenas para numeração de linhas, creio que resolva. **[Nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/29283/70)** apliquei o mesmo conceito para paginação de resultados, com um exemplo de como fazer a mudança do valor inicial do índice conforme as páginas.

Veja aplicado ao **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e75e7/7)**.

### Solução para T-SQL:

Em T-SQL fica mais fácil, já tem função pronta pra isso:

```
SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY campo1),
   t.campo1,
   t.campo2
FROM
   tabela t
```

Comment: Mysql = Gambiarra, como sempre :)

Comment: Pra quem não manja, funcionando pode vir até remendado com *duct tape* que tá sussa.

Answer (score 7):

Na linha do @Bacco , solução para o **Oracle**

```
SELECT
   ROWNUM,
   t.campo1,
   t.campo2
FROM
   tabela t
```

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo o exemplo acima, só fiz um tratamento para exibir o primeiro que diverge do id na tabela.

```
SET @contador := 0;
select linha,id from (SELECT
   @contador := @contador + 1 AS linha,
   t.id
FROM
   `TABLEX` t
   order by id) ttt where linha <> id
```

Comment: Marcos, seja bem vindo ao stackoverflow. Legal a sua contribuição, mas seria interessante que houvesse algum tipo de explicação na sua resposta baseado na pergunta do usuário, não apenas o código solto.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @FagnerFonseca

Answer (score 0):

**No Firebird**

Para que possamos adicionar um contador de linhas em um SQL no Firebird utiliza-se a função row_number().
Essa função permite que o firebird conte as ROWs e mostre o valor correspondente a cada uma durante o seu funcionamento, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
select row_number() over(),campo1,campo2 from tabelax;
```

Answer (score -2):

Para o oracle resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
with teste as (
SELECT  
        campo1,
        campo2
        
FROM 
        tabela
ORDER BY
      campo1
) 

SELECT ROWNUM AS SEQ, teste.* FROM teste;
```