# Setar posição de Auto Increment, sempre para o menor ID

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, chave-primária, auto-incremento

Tenho um banco de dados **MySQL**, onde contém uma tabela chamada `usuarios`

Nessa tabela contém uma coluna `ID`, onde é ***AutoIncrement*** e do tipo `INT`

Preciso que:

- Sempre que eu insiro o primeiro resultado o `ID` seja igual a `1`

Mas se apagar e voltar a inserir outro resultado:

- `ID` já deixa de ser `1` e passa a ser `2`

---

#### Como faço para ter sempre o menor `ID` que não tenha sido utilizado?

Comment: Através de um trigger.

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo, de como fazer?

Comment: Já respondi... me fale se funcionou!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Isso é padrão e sempre acontecerá.**

---

Se tiver 2 transações sobrepostas que estão fazendo `INSERTs`:

- A transação 1 faz um `INSERT`, obtém o `ID` **26** (por exemplo)
- A transação 2 faz um `INSERT`, obtém o `ID` **27**

Então:

- Se a transação 1 falhar, reverte a operação
- A transação 2 é concluída com `ID` **27**

---

Se os valores consecutivos fossem garantidos, cada transação teria que acontecer uma após a outra, ou seja, **perderia totalmente a escalabilidade**. Eu não me preocuparia com esse tipo de controle, pois parece pouco efetivo esse tipo de padronização dos dados.

> Caso a pergunta seja para efeito esclarecedor não vejo problema.
>
> **Mas para projetos não recomendo!**

Comment: Boa observação. E tem outra: se alguem deletar um ID no meio da sequência, vai ficar "buraco" de qualquer forma, a não ser que renumere tudo toda vez (ou faça algum algoritmo maluco para mover a maior de todas para o numero liberado, o que poria em dúvida a própria razão de ser da coluna). Se o Gonçalo precisa de numeração sequencial, provavelmente seria o caso de pegar o [numero posicional do registro após ordenação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43904/70), e não o ID.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira simples de conseguir isto é utilizando um `gatilho || trigger` na tabela onde deseja controlar o `auto_increment`.

Tente adaptar o exemplo abaixo à sua realidade.

Imaginemos uma `tabela_qualquer` que tenha a coluna `id int not null auto_increment`. O gatilho irá pegar o valor máximo desta coluna e incrementar 10 antes da inserção de dados.

```
create trigger usr_tg_tabela_qualquer BEFORE INSERT ON tabela_qualqer
    FOR EACH ROW
begin

DECLARE NEW_ID INT;

SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id),0) + 10 INTO NEW_ID FROM tabela_qualquer;

SET NEW.id = NEW_ID;
end;
```

Qualquer dúvida na sintaxe sugiro consultar a [Documentação Oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Comment: Deu erro, e não é bem isso que pretendo, pretendo fazer uma transação, de forma a que seje automatico.